# How do I Initialize a Bare Git directory with the files being tracking another directory?

Tags: git

I have a directory whose name cant be changed to add .git. This is causing some problems when I go to add the remote site as an Origin. Is it possible to initialize the bare repo within the directory and have it track outside its current directory?

```
Production
|_file1.txt
|_file2.txt
|_production.git
```

Comment: Bare repositories don't track files. It's non-bare repos track working directories. I think you want to create a non-bare repo inside `Production`. Just do `cd Production && git init`

Comment: I want multiple people to be able pull and push to the Production folder though

Comment: You need 2 repositories for that — one non-bare in `Production` and one bare outside but with a `post-receive` or `post-update` hook that does `cd Production && git pull` from bare.